# Prove the seq $\{\frac{x^4-1}{x^4+x-6}\}$ converges and prove using $N-\epsilon$ proof

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

Prove $$\{\dfrac{x^4-1}{x^4+x-6}\}$$ converges and prove using $N-\epsilon$ proof.

I see that this sequence approach $1$.

So,

I want to show:

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N>0, s.t, n>N \to |\dfrac{x^4-1}{x^4+x-6}-1| < \epsilon$$

I started this proof and was trying to find an ideal $N$.

$$|\dfrac{x^4-1}{x^4+x-6}-1| < \epsilon$$ 
$$|\dfrac{x^4-1}{x^4+x-6}-\frac{(x^4+x-6)}{x^4+x-6}| < \epsilon$$
$$|\dfrac{-1-x+6}{x^4+x-6}| = |\dfrac{5-x}{x^4+x-6}| = |\dfrac{x-5}{x^4+x-6}| < \epsilon$$

Now I wanted to do some bounding so I can make the function larger:

$$|\dfrac{x-5}{x^4+x-6}| \leq |\dfrac{x-5}{x^4}| \leq |\dfrac{2x}{x^4}| \leq |\dfrac{2}{x^3}|$$

but this is not the case when I graph it. Where is my bounding wrong?

[image]

As you can see, the red graph is actually **bigger** then the blue graph. Why?

Comment: You need $x \geq 6$

Comment: Obviously $x^4+x-6\not\geq x^4$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R} $. Take $x=1$, for example. As @JairTaylor mentions, it's obvious from this you need $x\geq 6$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a larger functin?

Comment: Don't need a larger function. You need larger values of x.  try it for 6<x < say 50.  You don't need to worry about red being bigger *sometimes*.  Jest that it is true for large x.  This is true if x > 6.  So it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$|\dfrac{x-5}{x^4+x-6}| < \epsilon$

Now start bounding $N$

Suppose $N> 6$

$|x-5| < N\\
|x^4+x-6| > N^4$

$|\dfrac{x-5}{x^4+x-6}| < \frac 1{N^3}$

$\frac 1{N^3} = \epsilon\\
N = \max (6,\frac {1}{\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}})$

Comment: How did you assume $N$ must be $> 6$, if you didn't have the graph?

Comment: I chose N=6 because so that $x>N \implies (x^4 + x - 6)>x^4$

Comment: Yes, but how did you conclude that? Did you mentally graph the image?

Comment: I wanted the $(x-6)$ part of that expression to be greater than $0$.

Comment: Got it, thank you Doug

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $n\ge 2$, $n^4+n-6\ge n^4/2$.  Hence we can write

$$\left|\frac{n^4-1}{n^4+n-6}-1\right|=\left|\frac{n-5}{n^4+n-6}\right|\le \frac{n}{n^4/2}=\frac{2}{n^3}<\epsilon$$

whenever $n>(2/\epsilon)^{1/3}$.

Comment: $n^4+n-6\ge n^4$ for $n\ge6$ is easier. `;-)`

Comment: Isn't this what I wrote?

Comment: So my soln works?

Comment: @egreg Easier?  How does one quantify ease here? ;-))

Comment: @KSplitX Your final inequality was the same, but the way it was developed had a flaw.  Note that you have tacitly assumed that $n^4+n-6\ge n^4$.  This is not true unless $n\ge 6$.  So, your value of $N$ is correct, but the way it was obtained needs a tweek.